# Number of distinct functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Question: **"How many distinct functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ are there, from the set $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to the set $C=\{1,2,3\}$, such that for all $j\in C$, there are exactly two distinct elements $i\in B$ such that $f(i)=j$; in other words, such that for all $j\in C$, $\bigl\vert\{i\in B \mid f(i) =j\}\bigr\vert=2$?"**

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to go about it.

There are $3$ elements in set $C$. We can pick two elements of set $B$ in $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\
   2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ ways. So there are a total of $3\cdot 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\
   2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=45$ distinct functions with the condition required by the question.

Answer (score 2):

There must be two elements of B that are mapped to $1$.  You can choose those in $6 \choose 2$ ways.  Two of the remaining ones must be mapped to $2$.  How many ways can you choose those?  You have two elements left, which must be mapped to $3$.

Comment: Do you mean $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    4 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix} = 15\cdot 6\cdot 1 = 90
$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This is the number of partitions of $B$ into three $2$-sets, multiplied by the number of permutations of $C$.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
    6 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \cdot 3! = 15\cdot 6 = 90$

Comment: $\binom 62$ is the number of $2$-sets, not the number of partitions into three $2$-sets.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a partition please?

Comment: Here, three subsets which do not intersect pairwise, and the union of which is the whole set.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Could you help me with the total number of partitions of $B$ into three $2$-sets?

Comment: You've already done the computation in your comment above to @Ross Millikan's answer. Is that enough?